# Has anyone implemented ScrollCaptureCallback successfully in a Compose app?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, screenshot

I'm trying to utilize the scrolling screenshot feature of android 12 in my app, but it looks like something is needed in the screen order for it to work, the only thing I have found on the topic is [ScrollCaptureCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScrollCaptureCallback) but there isn't documentation on how to implement it. Has anyone tried this?

I've tried to look into how to apply a View function in a composable, but other than developing the screen as a view instead of composables I haven't found any other way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it would be feasible to implement this on the level of app code instead of the Compose framework itself, where it is currently missing. According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197906322, it seems to exist on the Compose team's backlog.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the issue. I've tried the feature in multiple apps and yes, it seems like a compose issue, but I wasn't sure because some apps that are supposedly made with compose (like Airbnb) seem to work fine, but maybe they don't use compose in the whole app.

I will keep track of the issue and answer this question if anything changes.